# Should we remove "Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced" from the tour?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tour

The [Tour](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tour) has a useful section about what sorts of questions new users should be asking:

[image]

In my opinion, saying *"Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced."* would encourage personal advice questions, which are not allowed on the site. The tour itself says that such questions are off-topic, but the two statements seem to contradict each other.

Should we remove or edit the highlighted text?